# How large are Starship Cores?

Tags: vehicles, starfinder

A PC wants to store a starship core in a Null-sec Chamber, but I cannot find any information regarding the actual physical size of a starship core and the safety equipment that goes along with it.

Based on the Cries from the drift map (they show a ship with an engine room) a 10x15 space can contain all of the engine and engine housing. Assuming by engine they mean a core I'm thinking only a mk4 will fit a core. This seems very small considering a core housing takes up an entire expansion bay. But based on hangar sizes multiple tiny ships, with cores, can fit into a expansion bay's worth of space.

Overall, the size of cores does not seem well defined, so any help deciding on a general size for dealing with cores in game would be greatly appreciated.

**Is there any information I haven't found about the general size of starship components?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is no information about the real size of starship components

I waited until I got my hands on the (newly released) [Armory](http://paizo.com/products/btpya1rr?Starfinder-Armory) so I could be certain of this. But no, apparently they left out the actual sizes of ship components on purpose. Simply because two different starship designs will be different from one another, one race may design ships with a material that can save some space, while another wastes a lot of space with internal/external decoration.

So, even though some starship maps have a defined size for many things, those sizes haven't been *consistent* among the released maps, as can be seen [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DSqqHxoVQAAoBWQ.jpg), which shows three different starships of the same size from the same artist.

However, it seems the developers made some mistakes on the starship size and weight measurements, as can be seen by the [several](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uims?The-big-Starships-seem-oddly-lightwieght) [threads](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uj1x?Starfinders-Strange-Starship-Sizes#1) [open](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uhxs?Starship-Length-Volume-and-Mass#1) on that subject.